# how to make a full screen image by using WindowManager on Nexus 7

Tags: android

I have an app which runs a service to show an image every other second (basically it should cover Everything on screen every other second).

This is the code in onCreate() of the Service class. So I put the image by usuing Another activity which uses the image by having it in `android:background="@drawable/image"`

```
 params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        // params.flags= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

             mTopView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_invisible, null);         
            windowManager.addView(mTopView, params);
```

Even i tried to add the image directly to the `WindowManager` but still the image is not full screen (by full screen i mean it will cover Everything in screen, even the titlebar)
I thought maybe using the image as background in the activity and then setting the manifest for that activity to  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"`will help. But it didnt.

Do you have any ideas how can I accomplish this?

(Also I tried to use dimming - as you can see the flags in the commented code- to make the whole screen black instead of adding an image to hide Everything, but there is some timing problems with dimming and doesnt work properly in android)

I appreciate some help
Update: it works on my phone (samsung galaxy) but not on my nexus 7

Here is the screenshot in my Nexus 7 device (the White image is not covering the whole screen as you can see):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

You can hide the status bar using two ways :

1) Define below line in your activity `onCreate()` method.

```
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

2)Define the theme at the application level not to show the status bar through out application as below:

> ```
> <application android:label="@string/app_name"
>   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
> ```

Comment: if you read my question I wrote that i used this method and it didnot help!